# Error 503 Service Unavailable on Dedicated server

Tags: iis, http

We have problem with Go daddy Dedicated Server hosting (Windows Hosting). This server crash on just **400 Active users**.(**Error massage is 503**) & when we restart server its start again. but within 24hr we face that same problem. We regularly clear IIS pool. and also server **kill random HTTP requests** of users. Now what can i do Please give some suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Welcome and thank you for posting. Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) , [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and contains sufficient details to provide you with a good solution. Posting the errors displayed to your website users is inadequate, you want to investigate the actual (event-)log messages and the cause of your errors. Please improve your question to address those points or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find out the exact reason why it starts giving out a 503 error. It could be resource exhaustion or configuration issue.

If it is a configuration problem, then you change configuration to allow more simultaneous requests.

If it is resource exhaustion, then you can do the following things:

You can optimize your web application so that it doesn't consume that much resources. It isn't possible to give any further details on this as it is highly dependent on the web application itself how the optimization should be done.

You can upgrade the server to a more powerful one that can handle the load.